# Mac OSX: Adobe Flash player 10.1.85.3 text issue

Tags: macos, fonts, flash, flash-player

Running Flash Player 10.1.85.3. on OS-X 10.6.4

I've run into a very strange issue with Adobe/Macromedia Flash.  Text in dialogs sometimes is not displayed, and the containing boxes are distorted.  It occurs in all browsers.  This is best demonstrated on YouTube in some of their ads, as well as in Google Analytics overlays on graphs.

You can see the issue here:
[image]

As you can see, where I have moused over the high point, there should be a dialog with some text, but instead it is quite broken.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Flash plugin several times, reinstalling Google Chrome, validating my fonts with FontBook (removed all dupes/ fonts with warnings).  Also as a last resort I checked/ repaired perms on my disk.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try deleting your Flash preferences:

`rm -r /Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash\ Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys`

`mkdir /Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash\ Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys`

`rm -r /Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash\ Player/#SharedObjects`

`mkdir /Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash\ Player/#SharedObjects`

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately it didn't work -- still experiencing the same issue.  Thanks for the suggestion though!